# Moving the source line to the left

Tags: tables

Hey when I'm creating tables, I'm having trouble getting the last line, my "source line" to the left underneath my table.

Can anyone help, I've tried moving the line of code and tried adding

```
\noindent
```

But I can't figure out how to do it

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\rot}[2]{\rule{1em}{0pt}% 
    \makebox[0cm][c]{\rotatebox{#1}{\ #2}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {15cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Værdipolitik}} \\
    \textbf{Social Tillid}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Total}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Total}} \\
    &Antal&Antal&Antal&Antal&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \% \\
    \midrule
    Høj tillid&7&50&105&162&43.8\%&65.8\%&84.0\%&74.7\% \\
    Moderat tillid&9&23&19&51&100.0\%&96.1\%&99.2\%&98.2\% \\
    Lav tillid&0&3&1&4&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
    \textbf{Total}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{N}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }Kvant Projekt 2016}
\normalsize
\end{center}
```

If anyone can see what I'm missing, I would really appreciate it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Move `\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }Kvant Projekt 2016}` out of the centering environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring far too many columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rot}[2]{%
  \makebox[0cm][l]{\hspace{-.5em}\rotatebox[origin=bl]{#1}{\ #2}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\footnotesize\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {@{} l *{8}{Y} @{}} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Værdipolitik}} \\
\textbf{Social Tillid}&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Total}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}\hfill\null&
  \rot{30}{\textbf{Total}}\hfill\null \\
&Antal&Antal&Antal&Antal&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \% \\
\midrule
Høj tillid     &  7 & 50 & 105 & 162 &  43.8\% &  65.8\% &  84.0\% &  74.7\% \\
Moderat tillid &  9 & 23 &  19 &  51 & 100.0\% &  96.1\% &  99.2\% &  98.2\% \\
Lav tillid     &  0 &  3 &   1 &   4 & 100.0\% & 100.0\% & 100.0\% & 100.0\% \\
\textbf{Total} & 16 & 76 & 125 & 217 \\
\midrule
\textbf{N}     & 16 & 76 & 125 & 217 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\multicolumn{9}{@{}r@{}}{\scriptsize\emph{Source:} Kvant Projekt 2016}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move `\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }Kvant Projekt 2016}` out of the centering environment and notice also that `\scriptsize` doesn't have an argument--just put it inside the braces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\newcommand{\rot}[2]{\rule{1em}{0pt}% 
    \makebox[0cm][c]{\rotatebox{#1}{\ #2}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {15cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Værdipolitik}} \\
    \textbf{Social Tillid}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Total}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Højreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Central orienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Venstreorienteret}}&\rot{30}{\textbf{Total}} \\
    &Antal&Antal&Antal&Antal&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \%&Kum \% \\
    \midrule
    Høj tillid&7&50&105&162&43.8\%&65.8\%&84.0\%&74.7\% \\
    Moderat tillid&9&23&19&51&100.0\%&96.1\%&99.2\%&98.2\% \\
    Lav tillid&0&3&1&4&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
    \textbf{Total}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{N}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
}
{\scriptsize\emph{Source: }Kvant Projekt 2016}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table overflows into the margin. I propose this code, based on `xparse` and `threeparttable`. I define a  `\myrothead` command, with an optional argument, to shift the horizontal position of the beginning of the rotated text in its cell (default: 1.2em). The vertical spacing with the above row has to be set manually, with an `\addlinespace[xxx]` command. I removed the `%` in cells, as they're already found in the column heads.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate, rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttable}%

\usepackage{xparse}%
 \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\myrothead{O{1.2em} m m}{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\protect\hspace{#1}\turnbox{#2}{\textbf{#3}}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {@{} l*{8}{Y}@{}} \\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Værdipolitik}} \\
\addlinespace[12ex]
    \textbf{Social Tillid}&\myrothead{30}{Højreorienteret}&\myrothead{30}{Central orienteret}&\myrothead{30}{Venstreorienteret}& \myrothead{30}{Total} &\myrothead[0.6em]{30}{Højreorienteret}&\myrothead[0.6em]{30}{Central orienteret} & \myrothead[0.6em]{30}{Venstreorienteret} &\myrothead[0.6em]{30}{Total} \\
    &Antal&Antal&Antal&Antal& Kum\,\% & Kum\,\% & Kum\,\% & Kum\,\% \\
    \midrule
    Høj tillid&7&50&105&162& 43.8 & 65.8&84.0 &74.7 \\
    Moderat tillid&9&23&19&51&100.0 &96.1 &99.2 &98.2 \\
    Lav tillid&0&3&1&4&100.0 &100.0 &100.0 &100.0 \\
\addlinespace
    \textbf{Total}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{N}&16&76&125&217&&&& \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]
\scriptsize
\item[\emph{Source:}] Kvant Projekt 2016.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this, and the comment below, were exactly what I was looking for